# asp.net: недействительный аргумент обратной передачи или обратного вызова

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Возникла ошибка:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +11677786
   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +149
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +87
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +644
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +988

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.9037.0
```

Мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="NumberType" runat="server" Text="Числові типи даних" OnClick ="NumberTypeChecked()" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="WorkWithCurrency" runat="server" Text="Тип для роботи з валютою" OnClick="WorkWithCurrencyChecked()" />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTypeColums" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="NameColums" runat="server"  Width="300px" Height="100px"></asp:ListBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="AddInformColums" runat="server" Text="Додати" OnClick="AddInformColums_Click"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function NumberTypeChecked() {
            let NumberType = document.getElementById("NumberType");
            let WorkWithCurrency = document.getElementById("WorkWithCurrency");
            

            if (NumberType.checked) {
                let DropDownListTypeColums = document.getElementById("DropDownListTypeColums");

                DropDownListTypeColums.innerHTML = "";

                let ArrayValues = [
                    "serial",
                    "smallserial"
                ];

                for (let i = 0; i < ArrayValues.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = ArrayValues[i];
                    option.value = ArrayValues[i];
                    DropDownListTypeColums.appendChild(option);
                }

                WorkWithCurrency.checked = false;
            }
        }

        function WorkWithCurrencyChecked() {
            let NumberType = document.getElementById("NumberType");
            let WorkWithCurrency = document.getElementById("WorkWithCurrency");
            

            if (WorkWithCurrency.checked) {
                

                DropDownListTypeColums.innerHTML = "";

                let ArrayValues = [
                    "money"
                ];

                for (let i = 0; i < ArrayValues.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = ArrayValues[i];
                    option.value = ArrayValues[i];
                    DropDownListTypeColums.appendChild(option);
                }
                NumberType.checked = false;
                
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ошибка происходит в тот момент, когда выбираю один из `checkbox` и в  `DropDownList` передаются значения. После нажимаю на кнопку и вуаля.

Как понял, сервер дал нам пустой `DropDownList`, а мы его заполнили и в этом проблема. Как мне быть с ней?

Прочитал, что поможет `EnableEventValidation="false"`, но не рекомендуют из-за безопасности. Есть другие варианты исправить?
Добавлю : при нажатии на кнопку, нужно значения из `DropDownList` переместить в `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал немного по другому, не уверен что правильно или "красиво" но все же оно работает :
В `Button` добавил событие `OnClientClick` и добавил функцию `AddInformColums_Click()`.
Вот что получилось :
HTML :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="NumberType" runat="server" Text="Числові типи даних" OnClick ="NumberTypeChecked()" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="WorkWithCurrency" runat="server" Text="Тип для роботи з валютою" OnClick="WorkWithCurrencyChecked()" />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTypeColums" runat="server" Width="200px" OnChange=""></asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="NameColums" runat="server"  Width="300px" Height="100px"></asp:ListBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="AddInformColums" runat="server" Text="Додати" OnClientClick="AddInformColums_Click()"/>
            
        </div>
    </form>
```

JS :

```
function AddInformColums_Click() {
            event.preventDefault();
            let name = document.getElementById("DropDownListTypeColums").value;
            let NameElement = document.getElementById("NameColums");
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = name;
            NameElement.add(option)
        }
        function NumberTypeChecked() {
            let NumberType = document.getElementById("NumberType");
            let WorkWithCurrency = document.getElementById("WorkWithCurrency");
            

            if (NumberType.checked) {
                let DropDownListTypeColums = document.getElementById("DropDownListTypeColums");

                DropDownListTypeColums.innerHTML = "";

                let ArrayValues = [
                    "serial",
                    "smallserial"
                ];

                for (let i = 0; i < ArrayValues.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = ArrayValues[i];
                    option.value = ArrayValues[i];
                    DropDownListTypeColums.appendChild(option);
                }

                WorkWithCurrency.checked = false;
            }
        }

        function WorkWithCurrencyChecked() {
            let NumberType = document.getElementById("NumberType");
            let WorkWithCurrency = document.getElementById("WorkWithCurrency");
            

            if (WorkWithCurrency.checked) {
                

                DropDownListTypeColums.innerHTML = "";

                let ArrayValues = [
                    "money"
                ];

                for (let i = 0; i < ArrayValues.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = ArrayValues[i];
                    option.value = ArrayValues[i];
                    DropDownListTypeColums.appendChild(option);
                }
                NumberType.checked = false;
                
            }
        }
```